# How to resolve these prettier errors in express, typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, prettier, eslintrc

I have setup a basic app Node/Express + Typescript project

```
app.listen(PORT, (): void => {
  console.log(`app running in ${environment} listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I am getting error and I am not sure why?

> Replace `PORT,` with `⏎··PORT,⏎·` (prettier/prettier)
>
> Insert `··` (prettier/prettier)
>
> Replace `}` with `··},⏎` (prettier/prettier)

If I try and fix these error which are displayed (in Codacy dashboard) Vscode shows eslint error. I am not sure how to mute as Codacy is probably reading it from eslintrc file.
eslintrc configs looks like as below

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint', 
    'plugin:prettier/recommended', 
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018, 
    sourceType: 'module', 
  },
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'array-callback-return': 'error',
    // "no-console": "error",

    // these we probably do not care about
    '@typescript-eslint/array-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```

any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and fixed it.

The reason for the problem was that my local Prettier was an outdated one, but the Codacy was using the latest version of the Prettier. So I was not able to see any error on my local code, but the errors were there on the Codacy after pushing the code.

Finally, I updated my local Prettier & restarted the VSCode to changes be applied. Then the problem got fixed.